# Как сохранить текст в поле textField на другой ViewController

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield

Помогите пожалуйста.
Есть два ViewController, на первом TableView а на втором TextField и кнопка в Bar Button Item "Done".
Как реализовать сохранение текста в TextField на первый ViewController в TableView по кнопке "Done" ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете либо передать значение в контроллер, либо сохранить удобным способом (например UD). В вашем случае я бы передавал как параметр.